# Powershell - path's format is not supported when variables in the file name

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to add an XML declaration to multiple files in a directory. The code works for a single file with hard-coded name but when I want to run it for multiple files, I'm getting the following error:

> "Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's
>   format is not supported."

I'm using:

```
$FilePath = C:\test
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath\*.xml
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$decl = $xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ucs-2", "yes")
$xml.InsertBefore($decl, $xml.DocumentElement)
$xml.save($FilePath$file)
}
```

I've been changing the last line to

```
$xml.save($FilePath+"\"+$file)
$xml.save("$FilePath\$file")
```

and other formats but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xml.save("$file")  ?

```
$FilePath = "C:\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath\*.xml
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$decl = $xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ucs-2", "yes")
$xml.InsertBefore($decl, $xml.DocumentElement)
$xml.save($file)
}
```

or

```
$FilePath = "C:\Scripts"
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath\*.xml
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$decl = $xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ucs-2", "yes")
$xml.InsertBefore($decl, $xml.DocumentElement)
$xml.save($FilePath + $file.Name)
}
```

As $file is full:\path\of\file\plus\filename.xml you are trying to add full:\path to it.

$file or $Filepath + $File.Name will work.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that before and am getting an error: "Access to the path 'C:\abc.xml' is denied." so it seems like it needs the full path to save in the correct directory. abc.xml is the file in C: , not sure why it is being picked up

Comment: The second solution worked, I just needed to add "\". $xml.save($FilePath + "\" + $file.Name) . Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to chime in on this: Remember that $file is an object with attributes, one of which is "name". Set a breakpoint inside the loop and look at $file | get-member

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and I was able to get what I needed by joining strings using the **-join** command to create a new var. In this case we'll call it *$XMLCompatibleFileNames*.

```
$FilePath = C:\test
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath\*.xml
foreach ($file in $files)
{
$xml = [xml](get-content $file)
$decl = $xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ucs-2", "yes")
$xml.InsertBefore($decl, $xml.DocumentElement)
# Join your vars as strings and add the wack (\) if not included in the directory var
# Test it with write-host $XMLCompatibleFileName
$XMLCompatibleFileName = -join ("$($FilePath)\","$($File)")
$xml.save($XMLCompatibleFileName)
}
```